# Adding new page layout - Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, controller

I created new xml layout, all phtmls needed for it and put the action method in controller but I can't get it working because url that is defined in controller doesn't point to new xml layout I made previously.

To be precise, I added my_password.xml into layout/account folder:

```
<customer_account_passwordup_index>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/my_account_page.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_password" name="customer.account.password.update" template="customer/account/password_update.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_passwordup_index>

<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation" >
         <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>password_update</name><path>customer/account/passwordup</path><label>My Password</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>

 <customer_account>
   <reference name="header">
    <action method="setTemplate">
    <template>page/html/customer_account_header.phtml</template></action>
 </reference>
</customer_account>
```

and added this into config.xml for Customer module:

```
        <updates>
            <customer module="Mage_Customer">
                <file>customer.xml</file>
            </customer>
            <customer_account_passwordup module="Mage_Customer">
                <file>account/my_password.xml</file>
            </customer_account_passwordup>
        </updates>
```

also added this to customer controller:

```
public function passwordupAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Password'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

now mysite.com/index.php/customer/account/passwordup/ opens up but it isn't connected to my_password.xml layout, it opens some default layout.

Do you have some suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this tag `<customer_account_passwordup_index>` to this one `<customer_account_passwordup>`.
The layout handle is built like this:

`module_controller_action`.
In your case the module is `customer` (by the way, don't modify the core...create a module for that), the controller name is `account` and the action name is `passwordup`.

Clear the cache and give it a go.

Comment: Thank you very much, life saver :)